# Using key combination in Java

Tags: java, key, combinations

I develop a Java application and need to enable entering special symbols by using a 'dead' key or key modifiers. For example, the user should be able to enter 'ñ' by pressing '`+n'.

I considered using key listeners but any event fired by a key is processed before the document is changed and I cannot alter that change. I also cannot change the key itself to allow direct entering the required symbol.

Please advise.

Comment: Why don’t you use the standard input elements for text input? They already process dead keys correctly without you needing to do anything about it.

Comment: I have never seen anything about those standard input elements. Can you give more details or point to documentation?

Comment: Maybe you are thinking too complicated? I’m talking about text fields, text areas, editor panes or whatever fits your use case.

Comment: I think about them, too. But I cannot find anything helpful.

Comment: What I think @Holger is suggesting is that users ought to be able to rely on their operating system to insert characters; that way your application doesn't need to directly support dead keys and the like.  For instance, here's how to [type © on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/25768/12220).  This should work in a Java GUI application just like any other application.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is too good to be true. For example, I cannot enter 'ñ' (and many other symbols) on my ThinkPad T420 with Windows 7 using operating system only. I tried every way I could find on the Internet.

Comment: Sounds like you should simply install a different keyboard layout. E.g. I use the [NEO keyboary layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Neo) and have no problems entering `ñ`, etc. regardless of the application. However, if you insist on a Java solution, have a look at the [Input Methods API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/imf/index.html).

Comment: I do not insist on a Java solution. I just could not use any of keyboard layouts that I tried on my laptop. I also do not want to add that another layout to three that I already have. Lastly, I looked at NEO but could not figure out how to work with it as the entire site is in German.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that KeyEvent.setKeyChar() method called from a key listener can replace the entered char. This allowed me to make char translation using ESC key as the prefix.