# How to press combination of keys using java

Tags: java

Can I press combination of keys in java like alt+F4 or alt+Shift+Z!
I have tried my best to do this and follow to many instruction but in vain please help me!

I am follow [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246698/using-key-combination-in-java)

Comment: try Robot class in java

Comment: You can press whatever keys you want. Do you mean you want a Java application to press those keys? Or you want Java to detect those keys being pressed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send CTRL+Z keyEvent in java using Robot class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047710/how-to-send-ctrlz-keyevent-in-java-using-robot-class)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [Robot class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

You can make a keypress easily:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(/*keycode*/);//keycode that you want
```